# how to map tow js lists to one list of pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two lists with the same length

I want to use angular js to create a repeated ui table.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="pair in pairs ..>
```

say `[1,2,3,4]` and `[a,b,c,d]` would be

table:

```
1 row: 1 a

2 row: 2 b

3 row: 3 c

4 row: 4 d
```

How can i do this?

join the two lists and then repeat in angular? or do some double repeat?

Comment: Please elaborate your question better. What is the output you want, given those 2 arrays?

Comment: Sorry forgot. Added

Comment: will these list always be of the same length @EladBenda ?

Comment: yes. i set it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `ng-repeat` on `list1`.
2. Print its elements with using expression (`{{}}`)
3. Use `$index` as an index to get the value from the other array

This is how you do it

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.list1 = [1,2,3,4];
$scope.list2 = ["a","b","c","d"];

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="list in list1">
       {{list}}  row : {{list}}  {{list2[$index]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to combine both arrays into one, something like:

```
var $scope.pairs = [] ;

for (var i = 0 ; i < Array_1.length ; i++) {
    $scope.pairs.push( {number: Array_1[i] ,
                        letter: Array_2[i]  } ;
}
```

and your html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pair in pairs>
   <td>
      {{pair.number}} - {{pair.letter}}
   </tr>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '$index' from the iterator to get the value from the other array

```
//controller
$scope.pairs = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.otherArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
//template
<tr ng-repeat="pair in pairs">
   <td>{{ pair }}</td>
   <td>{{ otherArray[$index] }}</td>
</tr>
```

This will work of the arrays have the same length (this is something you will have to assume).